# Unpack only a single dependency from maven respository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

Is it possible to unpack only one dependency and leaving out the rest of the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml,using unpack-dependencies.

regards,
Sushma.

Comment: Have you tried using the `unpack` option in http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using unpack I used goal "copy " to achieve my requirement. Hence closing this question